# How to feed multiple time series sets into LSTM model for prediction?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, time-series

I am trying to take [this](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/News+Popularity+in+Multiple+Social+Media+Platforms) dataset and predict news popularity levels over time.

The dataset is made up of 145 columns (1 being the ID linked to the actual news story in a separate file, 2 - 145 for 144 20-minute time slices where each cell in a row records the popularity level of the corresponding news story).

I have already normalized the dataset "Facebook_Economy.csv" to range from 0 to 1. At the moment I can only feed a single time series set into my model (train ~100 time slices and test ~44 time slices). My aim is to take several rows of 144 time slices to train on and test on several other rows, e.g., take the time series data for news stories 1-20 and train on news stories 21-30, etc.

This is how I am currently feeding data into my model:

```py
def run(filename):
    series = read_csv(filename, header=0, index_col=0)

    repeats = 1
    results = DataFrame()
    timesteps = 1

    for i in range(len(series)):
        results['results'] = experiment(repeats, series.iloc[i].squeeze(), timesteps)
        # Where experiment(repeats, series, timesteps)
        print(results.describe())
```

As well (for some insight into how the rest of my code looks) I have been following [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-timesteps-lstm-networks-time-series-forecasting/) tutorial from Jason Brownlee for some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood well the question but I think I already did something similar. First, you have to stack all your features in an array. I found this link very helpful : https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-multi-step-time-series-forecasting-of-household-power-consumption/

Here is the code I use : (fen_pred = input size, n_output = output size)

```
    dataset_train_features = np.hstack((dataset_train,new_features_train,ssa_feature1_train,ssa_feature2_train))

    dataset_train_labels = dataset_train

    features_set = list()  
    labels = list() 

    # X_train

    for i in range(fen_pred, len_train):  
        if(len(dataset_train_features[i:i+n_output])<n_output):
            break
        features_set.append(dataset_train_features[i-fen_pred:i])

    for i in range(fen_pred, len_train):  
        if(len(dataset_train_labels[i:i+n_output])<n_output):
            break
        labels.append(dataset_train_labels[i:i+n_output])

    X_train=np.array(features_set)    
    y_train=np.array(labels)
```

(please note that i want to predict timesteps on one timeserie, that's why I don't predict multiple features)

In your case I would edit the array dataset_train_features, add every feature you need to train your model in this array and then reproduce this technique to create your test set.